# Error when installing package rattle in R on Mac OS X

Tags: r, macos

I'm trying to install the package `rattle` in R, but in the end I always get the same error no matter what I try:

installing to `/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/RGtk2/libs`

```
** R      
** demo     
** inst    
** preparing package for lazy loading     
** help    
*** installing help indices     
** building package indices     
** testing if installed package can be loaded     
objc[47575]: Class GNotificationCenterDelegate is implemented in both /opt/local/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib and /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgio-2.0.0.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.   
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RGtk2', details:   
  call: .RGtkCall("S_gtk_builder_get_type", PACKAGE = "RGtk2")      
  error: object has no G type    
Execution stopped   
ERROR: loading failed   
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/RGtk2’      
* restoring previous ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library/RGtk2’
```

I've read several posts to fix problems when installing rattle on OS X (I'm running El Capitan 10.11.6) like setting `dependencies = TRUE`, installing mac ports to work around the problem, placing the pkg-config file in the right folder etc. .. but nothing worked so far.

Can anyone see what this error is about? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How are you installing this package ? On my mac (Sierra), both rattle and RGtk2 (which seems to be the problem here) are available as binary that you can get with `install.packages("rattle")` and `install.packages("RGtk2")`.

Comment: For your specific compilation problem, it looks like you have 2 version of the Glib library, one in /opt and the other in /usr/local. Did you try to install it using different package managers (eg. macports, brew or fink)?

Comment: I first of all installed R with homebrew. But then this error appeared: 

installation of the package 'RGtk2' has Exit-Status unequal 0

So I tried the work around version with mac ports from here 

https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/9405675

Now I also get the error with "Class GNotificationCenterDelegate is implemented in both ..." which I don't know how to handle

Comment: why don't you use MacOs dmg file available here: https://cran.r-project.org/ ? It's much easier than compiling everything. Howebrew and Macports are NOT compatible. You should uninstall everything from one of them (homebrew is better as it has more packages, imho).

Comment: I guess you are right and brew and macports are just not compatible.
When I installed R with homebrew I couldn’t install rattle. So I installed R with macports without uninstalling R with homebrew first, which led to the error „Class GNotificationCenterDelegate is implemented in both...“

So what I did now to make it work was:
- Brew uninstall R
- Followed all instruction from https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/9405675 again.. Ending up with install.packages(„RGtk2“, depen=T) and install.packages(„rattle“) which worked out fine then.

I really appreciate your help! Thanks a lot!